# pattern matching type Error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Below is the map1.scala file in IntelijIDEA

It seems i hit the wall once again. I have no idea why the following is error:

```
abstract class List[T] {
   def map[U](f: T => U): List[U] = {
     this match {
       case Nil => this
       case x :: xs => ???
     }
   }
 }
```

case Nil: pattern type is incompatible with expected type: found Nil.type expected List[T]
this: expression of type List[T] doesn't conform to expected type List[U]
x :: xs Pattern type incompatible found ::B required List[T]..

I tried everything... But still have this problem. However knows please respond.

Comment: `Nil` is a type of `List` from standard library and you compare it with your own class `List.` Rename your list to `MyList`, `MyNil` and do not confuse yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is some problems with your code:

- invariant type parameter T of List
- non-existent object Nil
- absent operator ::
- absent object :: with unapply function

Try this:

```
abstract class List[+A]
  def head: A
  def tail: List[A]

  def map[B](f: A => B): List[B] = 
    if (this == Nil) Nil 
    else new ::(f(head), tail map f)
}

case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  def head = ??? // not interested in throwing more appropriate exception
  def tail = ???
} 

case class ::[T](head: T, tail: List[T]) extends List[T]
```

Then you can use it

```
(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil).map(_.toString)
```

Comment: Maybe you need to extend `List[T]` in the case class `::[T]`

Comment: @Dmitry, After I did what you said, it keeps hitting me an error in (If this == Nil) Nil  [Expression of type Nil.type doesn't conform to expected type List[B]]

Comment: @Spartan I forget to make :: extending List[T]. Sorry.